# BigQuery: Convert count to row

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an old SQL table as follows:

```
-------------------------------------
| product | cached number of orders |
|-----------------------------------|
| iphone  | 3                       |
| pencil  | 2                       |
```

I would like to convert this data to the following format:

```
-----------
| product |
|---------|
| iphone  |
| iphone  |
| iphone  |
| pencil  |
| pencil  |
```

Doing this on an application layer would be extreme, as the actual table is much more big and complex.

Is there a solution to run a SELECT on the old table that will output the desired format? (I could temporarily import the old table to BigQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT product
FROM dataset.table,
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, cached_number_of_orders))
```

The `, UNNEST (...` part produces a row for every number between 1 and `cached_number_of_orders`, so you end up with the desired number of repetitions of the product.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and not necessarily has extreme practical value for this particular question (as it is already answered by Elliott the way you would ususually do this)

But I always like to see options - more options :o)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT product
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(REPEAT(product, number_of_orders), product)) product
```

you can test with dummy data from you question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'iphone' product, 3 number_of_orders UNION ALL
  SELECT 'pencil', 2
)
SELECT product
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(REPEAT(product, number_of_orders), product)) product
```

with result

```
Row product  
1   iphone   
2   iphone   
3   iphone   
4   pencil   
5   pencil
```

Another [silly] variation of this :

```
#standardSQL
SELECT product
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
  UNNEST(SPLIT(REPEAT(CONCAT(product, ','), number_of_orders))) product
WHERE product <> ''
```